# Get Overall Rank

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I run the below sql server script to retrieve some data , but I need to add column to tell me in each LEAGUE which user is first, second and so on

```
Select 

(Select Name From League Where ID = League_Details.League_ID) As League
,Player
,(Select Total From AllUserPoints Where User_ID = Player) As Total


 From 
     League_Details

Where 
     LeagueType = 'Private'

order by League
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: I really recommend using a `JOIN` over those subqueries.

Comment: like this:

Select 

 b.Name
 ,a.Player
 ,c.Total
 

From 
 League_Details a  

 join League b on a.League_ID = b.ID
    join AllUserPoints c on a.Player = c.User_ID
 
Where 
 a.LeagueType = 'Private Classic League'

order by a.League_ID

Comment: And good aliases. `b` for `League`? There's no "b" in "League".

Comment: join League b on a.League_ID = b.ID

because i get the name of the league depend on ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `order by` properly in this statement.
Try this one:

```
Select (Select Name From League Where ID = League_Details.League_ID) As League
,Player, (Select Total From AllUserPoints Where User_ID = Player) As Total

 From 
     League_Details

Where 
     LeagueType = 'Private'

order by League, Total desc
```

Try this and Let me know whether it works on not.

Comment: Working for sorting but what i need adding column with rank order:

Rank
1
1
1
2

Comment: @IkramiHall Ok, Then you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you it's DONE:

Comment: Final Script, i added offset 0 rows because i store the script into view                                Select 

 b.Name as League
 ,a.Player
 ,c.Total
 ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.Name ORDER BY c.Total desc) AS Current_Rank
 

From 
 League_Details a  

 join League b on a.League_ID = b.ID
    join AllUserPoints c on a.Player = c.User_ID
 
Where 
 a.LeagueType = 'Private'

order by b.Name, c.Total desc offset 0 rows